# Python Pandas: Adding boolean columns to assist in filtering on one True value per record

Tags: python, pandas

How can pandas dataframe boolean columns be added together to create a column with the count of true values?

For example, the purpose is to create the 'count' column:

```
a       b       c       count
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   1
TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   2
TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    3
```

Following addition of booleans in python (e.g. True + True = 2), tried:

```
df.count = df.a + df.b + df.c
```

Which didn't work and produced warning:

```
UserWarning: evaluating in Python space because the '+' operator is not supported by numexpr for the bool dtype, use '|' instead
  unsupported[op_str]))
```

The purpose is to make it easier to filter on records that have only one True value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum` function, `.sum(1)` will count the trues for each row:

```
df['count'] = df[list("abc")].sum(1)
df
```

[image]